# Highcharts set date format on StockChart

Tags: datetime, highcharts, format

I am using PHP and highcharts to create some graphs, one of them is a StockChart.

I am having trouble to set the date on the xAxis. From server side (PHP) I pass the time period in miliseconds (I tried with other formats) and I'd like to show the date (e.g. YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM).

I receive the series data via JSON, small part of it is:

```
   [{... ,"time":[1409052660000,1409049060000,1409045460000, ...] }]
```

I can show the chart, the thing is that xAxis instead of having the date, it has a sequence for each date entry (00:00:00:50 00:00:00:100 00:00:00:150") ...

Any idea what am I missing or needs to be configured?

On client side I've configured:

```
var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'line',
                    marginRight: 250,
                },

                rangeSelector: {
                    //selected: 1,
                     //inputEnabled: $('#container').width() > 280,
                    //inputDateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d',
                    enabled: true
                },

                title: {
                    text: 'title',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: '',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    //tickPixelInterval: 50,

                    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                        millisecond: '%Y-%M-%D:%H'
                    }, 
                    labels: {
                     rotation: -45,
                    },
                    rangeSelector : {
                        //selected : 1,
                        //inputEnabled: $('#container').width() > 480
                        //enabled:true,

                    },
                    categories: []
                },
                yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
                    labels: {
                    rotation: 0,
                    format: '{value}',
                    style: {
                        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
                    },
                },
               title: {
                    text: '#',
                    style: {
                        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
                    }
            },


        }, { // Secondary yAxis
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            min: 0, max: 100,
             labels: {
                format: '{value} %',
                dashStyle: 'shortdot',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: '%',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            },
             opposite: true
         }],
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                            this.x +': '+ this.y;
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: -10,
                    y: 100,
                    borderWidth: 0
                },
                series: []
            }

  $.getJSON("query2.php",{cli: client_name}, function(json) {

            options.title.text = client_name;
            options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['time'];
            options.xAxis.type = 'datetime';
            //options.xAxis.rotation = -45;
```

//....

}

Comment: Seems you haven't decided if you want to use categories or datetime? Can't be both.

Comment: Hi Ondkloss, isn't the   `type: 'datetime'` doing this?

Comment: But you are setting `options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['time'];` in your JSON-callback function.

Comment: Ha I see. I changed to:  `options.xAxis.datetime = json[0]['time'];` and `xAxis: { type: 'datetime', datetime: [] ` } but also no success!

Comment: btw, In Highstock the x-axis is always a datetime axis! must be some other formating that I am missing!

Comment: In the highcharts options.xAxis.datetime doesnt exist, you need to set type as datetime and highcharts print dates. If you need custom xAxis you need to use [tickPositions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositions)